# Mixing two Mono and return first one with second in firsts body

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am facing a situation where I have to use 2 Mono where second one will be dependent on an Id field of first one and return the response of second one in the body of first Mono.

For example :

```
Mono<Article> first = fetchArticleById(id);

Mono<Rating> second = fetchRating(article.getRatingId()); //here I will use the response from 
first Mono,
```

then return the result as

```
/* this is the response of first Mono, the rating field is set by second Mono */
Article {
"id":1234,
"text" : "some text",
"rating" : "5 star", //fetched from second Mono
"ratingId":qq11
}
```

I have tried

```
first.map(art -> {
 return fetchRating(art.getRatingId());
});
```

But like this, I can only return response of second Mono.

By trying Map or Flatmap, it only works on the second mono.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetchArticleById(id)
  .flatMap(art -> fetchRating(art.getRatingId())
    .map(rating -> new Pair(art, rating)));
```

In the `map` function you have access to both article and rating, so you connect them as you need.

Comment: you can use `Tuple#of`